# Can Alexa control Kindle Fire's Wifi switch?

Tags: wi-fi, amazon-kindle-fire

My Kindle Fire has a habit of losing the connection to our wifi. Sometimes it shuts off; other times it just gets "weak". (Our other devices don't have this problem, so I know its not the wifi.)

This is my *real* problem; if you know a solution, please tell me.

Meanwhile, I notice that turning the wifi switch off and then on will reconnect it to our network. I tried to set up an Alexa Routine to do this every morning. The only Action that seemed to apply was "Custom", so I used that and tried these phrases:

*Alexa, turn on wifi* --> "Sorry, what device?"  (If I answer "Shawn's Fire" it does a web search.)

*Alexa, turn on wifi on this device* --> "Hmm. I don't know that."

*Alexa, turn on wifi on Shawn's Fire* --> "Sorry, I'm not sure about that"

Is there a way to get Alexa to turn the wifi off or on?

EDIT: @ChanganAuto pointed that Alexa can't do anything unless the Wifi is already connected. (Also, I thought the routines themselves were saved offline.)

So let me ask this: is there an app (or other method) that can turn the wifi on or off on a timed schedule, and do so while offline? (My phone has an app that can do that.)

Comment: How exactly are you expecting it to turn on a network device when said device isn't in the network?

Comment: I want the Fire to turn on its own Wifi switch, just like it can raise or lower its own volume. It should be able to do that while offline, and once the switch is on, it would connect to the network.

Comment: No, it shouldn't and it can't. Alexa doesn't work by telepathy, the device to be controlled has to be network connected already. This is what I tried to hint at in the first comment.

Comment: You're saying that routines aren't stored in the device, the way timers and alarms are? That's very disappointing. After all, my Android phone can do this.

Comment: No, it can't. To be clear: ANY form of remote control must rely on a physical or wireless connection to the device being controlled. Wireless are typically WiFi, Bluetooth, NFC or other form of (proprietary) RF Tx/Rx. In modern Android phones the first 2 are ubiquitous, NFC not so much, and that it. So, it is possible at least theoretically ton communicate through one technology and command it to switch on/off the others. Also in modern Android devices radios off / airplane mode actually switches off WiFi and/or Bluetooh and that's what we want. (...)

Comment: So, although it's *conceivable* a device being commanded to turn on WiFi via an alternative network connection - it actually isn't doable due to blatantly obvious security concerns but *technically* possible to program such action - the fact remains the controlled device must be on the network because Alexa works by connecting to networked devices, period. If your device isn't in the same network of the Alexa's device it can't be controlled and thatb is the end of the story. (...)

Comment: For sure, a WiFi can be just "listening", i.e., not connected to a given AP *ergo* not in an network and something communicate with it to do stuff including adding it to a known AP but that obviously implies the WiFi is already on so sending a command to turn it on is nonsensical. This illustrates the absurdity of what you want to do.